# Ionic route navigator

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

For some pages of my app I have `navigateRoot` which redirects users based on conditions but the problem of that is when user redirects to destination pages they'll lose ability of using back button.

## Example

If I use route links/buttons in my views I can use `routerDirection="forward"` in order to activate back button for users but in this case I'm not sure how I can use route direction

## Code

```
const addToko = this.addToko.value;
    this.storeService.store(
      addToko.name,
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.alertService.presentToast(data['message']);
        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/toko'); <-- redirect user here
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.presentToast(error['message']);
      }
    );
```

Now as this redirects are condition based I prefer to have static route for back button, sample logic below:

1- if user no have store, **redirect to intro page**

2- ***(here intro no have back button - based on sample code above)***

3- if user used back button in intro page **go to profile page**.

**any idea?**

Comment: is "this.navCtrl" type of the Router from @angular/router?

Comment: If you're using Ionic4/5 then you should use `router.navigate()`

Comment: @Y_Moshe yes `import { NavController, MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';`

Comment: @alex87 can you provide sample please?

Comment: are u sure the navigateRoot function exists in NavController? because I'm trying to search for it and i don't see that method...

Comment: @Y_Moshe  https://ibb.co/pZP6PFX

Answer (score 0):

well...

Going Root means that all existing pages in the stack will be removed...

so... If u don't want that u can use the regular router from '@angular/router' and setDirection as shown in that image

first u need to import { Router } from '@angular/router';

```
constructor (private router: Router) {}
```

and use it. like that:

```
const addToko = this.addToko.value;
this.storeService.store(
  addToko.name,
).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.alertService.presentToast(data['message']);
    this.navCtrl.setDirection('root');
    this.router.navigate('/toko'); // this should be the same without delete all ... i hope it helped,
  },
  error => {
    this.alertService.presentToast(error['message']);
  }
);
```

Comment: that means i have to change `this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/toko');` or add another one like `this.navCtrl.setDirection('/profile');` to get back button to work?

Comment: actually u maybe, not sure, need to omit that "this.navCtrl.setDirection('root');" because u don't want to delete the previous... so basically just use the angular router. give a try :)

Answer (score 0):

**IF ur using ionic version 4 follow this method**

### Normal page redirect

1. your page is parent.ts u gonna redirect to child page

   this.router.navigate(['\child'])
2. If u pass data with redirect use this method
   parent.ts

   let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
     state: {
       user: this.user
     }
   };
   this.router.navigate(['child'], navigationExtras);
   }

**child.ts**

1. data: any;

   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
       this.data = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.user;
     }
   });
   }

Comment: i know my code is not format u just copy paste it will help